# What is the meaning of "type* = nullptr"

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I don't undestand.

```
template<class T>
T foo2(T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value >::type* = nullptr) 
{
    return t;
}
```

**type* = 0**? What is this.

Comment: It's the same as `type* dummy_parameter = nullptr`, with the parameter name omitted. A parameter of type "pointer to `type`" and default value of `nullptr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a way of achieving [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae): The function can only be selected if all the types can be substituted in properly.

If `std::is_integral<T>::value` is `false` (i.e., `T` is not an integral type), [`std::enable_if<...>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) will have no member `type`, thus a substitution failure happens  and this function won't be called (and a different overload might).

If `T` is an integral type, then `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value >::type` will be `void`, so the second parameter will be of type `void*`. It is an unnamed parameter with default value `nullptr`, so you don't have to specify it.

So you would call it like this:

```cpp
foo2(0);  // T is `int`, which is integral, so the function can be called
foo2(0, nullptr);  // Same as above, but explicitly passing the parameter

// Can't call the function, because `double` is not integral,
// so second type is a substitution failure
// foo2(0.0);
```

Note that this would normally be achieved either with a default template parameter:

```cpp
// Same `void*` if integral, else substitution failure
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value >::type* = nullptr>
T foo2(T t)
{
    return t;
}

// Or alternatively with an `int` if integral, else substitution failure
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
T foo2(T t)
{
    return t;
}
```

Or directly in the return type:

```cpp
template<class T>
// Returns `T` if it's integral, else substitution failure
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type foo2(T t)
{
    return t;
}
```

And in C++20, you can use `requires` (or the [`std::integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/integral) concept in this case)

```cpp
template<class T> requires std::is_integral_v<T>
T foo2(T t)
{
    return t;
}

template<std::integral T>
T foo2(T t)
{
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++ you can, in a declaration of a function, omit the name of (a) parameter(s). This is a preferred style sometimes when separating an interface from an implementation to avoid having confusion between the names of the parameters of, say, a function prototype & an implementation. I have never quite seen someone do this before. But what they are then doing as @IgorTandetnik pointed out, is initialize that "dummy parameter" with a default value.